# Stained Clay Biome

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've heard that there's a new biome made of stained clay. Is this true? If it is true, what does it look like? Is there anything about it that I should know?

Comment: Please do some reasonable research before asking a question.  This is answerable by simply looking through the [wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft_Wiki)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The biome you are referring to is called the [Mesa biome](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mesa#Mesa). According to the Minecraft wiki

> Mesa is a rare, exotic biome made of hardened clay and stained clay, with dead bushes around similar to a desert. Red Sand will also generate here instead of regular sand, with occasional cacti. Its composition is useful when other sources of clay are scarce. However, finding a Mesa can be difficult due to their rarity.

Here is a screenshot of what they look like
[image: mesa biome]

And another with a river running through
[image: mesa biome with river]

Answer (score 0):

The "Stained Clay Biome" is actually a rare biome called mesa.  It is a bit like a desert but is filled with clay.  Instead of sand there is red sand which is pretty much the same.  And also there is cacti but there is only a few.